# \newcommand for stating middle or end of the month based on compile date

Tags: macros, conditionals, datetime

I am new to `\LaTeX` but am very excited to use it. At work I have a use for it for which it is perfect. Essentially we create the same report twice a month, which up til now has been done manually in Word. I would like to present this solution, which will offer huge time savings. Only problem is if there is any editing of code needed my boss will be hesitant. If I can present it in such a way that it just works he will not worry about other/future staff not understanding.

The rest of the document is working great, in the sense that all the moving parts change each runtime. But am stuck on going about making a command which would make the date stamp of the document either say middle or end of the current month? I think this should be possible.

Would trying to change something like `\datetime` be better than a new command? How would I go about doing either?

It will be going in the header as below.

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\chead{Mid-August}
```

Comment: I would not do this. What is if you for some reason recompile the Mid-August issue on september 1st? If the date is fix it should be set fixed in the code, too.

Comment: @Tobi: I assume that the OP will use a copy of the relevant file and changes the relevant contents and compiles that then?

Comment: @Tobi Just like Christian says. I believe it is easier to have it "just work" in normal usage and have to be edited for abnormal usage than always having to be manually edited. I do understand you concern though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TeX` provides the `\year`, `\month` and `\day` count registers, having the relevant date of compilation time (unless explicitly manipulated)

Querying with `\ifnum\day < 15` it's possible to ask whether it is the 'middle' of the month or rather towards the end. (Well, the precise definition is to specified ;-)

`datetime` is the predecessor of `datetime2`, but easier to use (in my opinion),  `\monthname[\the\month]` prints the name of the month.

I explicitly used the optional argument to show the manipulated values of `\month` and `\day`, omitting the optional argument forces `\monthname` to use the current value of the `\month` count register, which is in principle correct too since the current month shall be used anyway for the heading.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\chead{\ifnum\day < 15
  Mid-%
  \else
  End-%
  \fi%
  \monthname[\the\month]%
}


\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\clearpage
\day=10
\month=5
\blindtext[5]


\end{document}
```

Comment: @swoopdewoopzoom: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!