# How to typeset condition to show previous month?

Tags: macros, conditionals, datetime, date

I asked a previous question, which was answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326335/newcommand-for-stating-middle-or-end-of-the-month-based-on-compile-date), which answered my question, exactly as it had been asked.

```
\chead{\ifnum\day < 15
  Mid-%
  \else
  End-%
  \fi%
  \monthname[\the\month]%
}
```

However, this isn't exactly what is required. What I need it to do is give the name of the previous month  if it is the first 15 days of the month(ie. today would still be End-August) and give the current month if it is greater than 15.

Have tried creating a newcommand for `\prevmonth` but can't get that working.

```
\newcommand{\prevmonth}{\if\month=September%
August%
\fi%
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Thank you both very much. I have accepted Steven's response because it allows for both prefixes which is a must. That said, both answers work and may be useful to other people in future.

Comment: There was no statement that `Mid` is still necessary. If this would have been explicitly stated, I would have provided another solution :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about the revision of words like "Mid-" etc., but this variation of Christian's answer at the cited question may work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\chead{\ifnum\day < 15
  End-%
  \prevmonthname[\the\month]%
  \else
  End-%
  \monthname[\the\month]%
  \fi%
}
\def\prevmonthname[#1]{\ifcase#1%
  \or December\or January\or February\or March\or April\or May%
  \or June \or July \or August\or September\or October\or November\fi}


\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\clearpage
\day=10
\month=5
\blindtext[5]


\end{document}
```

Here is a version that takes Manuel's suggestion, but corrects for the "January" problem.  By doing it this way, one is not locked into English.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\chead{\ifnum\day < 15
  End-%
  \prevmonthname[\the\month]%
  \else
  End-%
  \monthname[\the\month]%
  \fi%
}
\def\prevmonthname[#1]{%
  \ifnum#1=1\relax\prevmonthnamehelp[13]\else\prevmonthnamehelp[#1]\fi}
\def\prevmonthnamehelp[#1]{\monthname[\the\numexpr#1-1\relax]}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\clearpage
\day=10
\month=5
\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't be more robust `\def\prevmonthname[#1]{\monthname[\the\numexpr#1-1\relax]}`?

Comment: @Manuel I think it would have the "January" problem that Christian struggle(s/ed) with.

Comment: Is the "January" problem just a problem for people using other languages?

Comment: @swoopdewoopzoom No, the January problem is the fact that when using the syntax, `\the\numexpr#1-1\relax` (as suggested by Manuel), to obtain the previous month number, the month of January will generate a `0`.  Then, when trying to accomplish `\monthname[0]`, the code breaks.  The solution is to trap month number `1` as a special case, and treat it differently.

Answer (score 5):

This assumes, that `End -` should always be the prefix ... and wraps around if the month is January and the number of day < 15.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcounter{auxmonth}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\chead{%
  \setcounter{auxmonth}{\month}%
  End - %
  \ifnum\day < 15\relax
  \ifnum\month = 1\relax
  \setcounter{auxmonth}{12}% Wrap around
  \else
  \addtocounter{auxmonth}{-1}% Really decrease the help-counter
  \fi
  \fi
  \monthname[\theauxmonth]%
}


\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\clearpage

\day=10
\month=1
\blindtext[5]


\clearpage

\day=20
\month=1
\blindtext[5]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need the `\expandafter`s?

Comment: @Manuel: It complained in a previous version, but I am using now another one

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I saw your profile, and am sad to see you go.  best wishes.

Answer (score 2):

if you are willing to switch to `datetime2`, the date can be calculated. Might be overkill, but it won't have any problems with January/Desember, and it will work with any language supported by the package.

The solution is based on the *alwaysask's* answer given in [Add (n) days to variable date](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318006/add-n-days-to-variable-date)

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\chead{End of\monthEnd{ourDate}
}


\newcount\daycount
\newcommand{\monthEnd}[1]{%
  \DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{#1}{-15}\daycount
  \DTMsavejulianday{newDate}{\number\daycount}
  \DTMmonthname{\DTMfetchmonth{newDate}}
}
\DTMsavedate{ourDate}{2016-07-14}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\clearpage
\DTMsavedate{ourDate}{2016-07-16}
\lipsum[1-5]



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Treat this as community wiki as the ideas here are mostly in the other solutions. Steven has created a `\premonthname` macro and Christian uses special counter `auxmonth`. Both of these seem unnecessary to me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\MonthName[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\or January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June
    \or July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December%
  \fi%
}
\newcommand\MyMonth{%
  \the\day\space\MonthName\month $\longrightarrow$ % if illistration nly
  \ifnum\day<15%
    \ifnum\month=1 December
    \else\MonthName{\numexpr\the\month-1}
    \fi%
  \else\MonthName\month\fi\newline%
}

\begin{document}\noindent
  \day=3 \month=1   \MyMonth
  \day=15 \month=1  \MyMonth
  \day=3 \month=8   \MyMonth
  \day=15 \month=8  \MyMonth
  \day=3 \month=12  \MyMonth
  \day=15 \month=12 \MyMonth
\end{document}
```

Comment: One may object that your solution will only work for the English language, where as my 'unnecessary' counter approach will apply `\monthname`, which is language settings aware

Comment: @ChristianHupfer True enough, but easily addressed by using the `datetime` package and using the language aware `\monthname` It defines instead of my `\MonthName`. Your counter really is unnecessary:)